# ExtJS Can i prevent field tooltip from overriding validation tooltip

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am assigning tooltips to a bunch of fields on render (to provide more info about each field). I have also have validations defined for each of these fields.

The normal tooltip shows by default on field hover. However on validation failure, the validation tooltip is not being present to the user. The normal tooltip is overriding the validation tooltip.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is a boolean method, called isValid, which can be called on fields. I would simply call this, check if its true, then render your tooltip, else don't.